# Strange (?) Xcode error message with ObjC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, message

Does anyone know what this message means (or when it raises)?

```
CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme
```

Comment: Without code posted, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme in a URL is what appears before the first colon.  For example, the scheme for the URL to this web page is `http`.  You are probably passing an incorrect URL into the function.  Set a breakpoint to see what you are passing in or log the URL.